# Renaming [piwik] to [matomo]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Followup to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363733/renaming-piwik-to-matomo

The Open Source project [piwik](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/piwik) has recently been renamed to "Matomo".

https://matomo.org/blog/2018/01/piwik-is-now-matomo/

It would be nice if here the [piwik](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/piwik) tag could be renamed to [matomo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matomo) (as on StackOverflow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a tag synonym and merging the tags seems like the right thing to do to me.  This does appear to be an official change.

- The website piwik.org redirects
- StackOverflow has already made a similar tag change

The tag synonym and move has now been completed.

I've also edited the tag wiki to reflect the new name.

Comment: Sounds like the way to go to me

Comment: Ì agree as apart from the name nothing has changed. The software and team is still the same.